# want to add Node.js support with Android source

Tags: android, node.js, build, build.gradle, android-source

I am new with Node.js.
I have a requirement to add support of Node.js with our current Android source code.
Can any one suggest, how I can proceed and what I would require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by downloading nodejs package from https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ and after cross compiling with NDK.
I am able to use nodejs with my android device after this.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not clear, try to clarify it.

Probably required to create APIs and/or Request/Response handlers to interact with Android application via Websocket or HTTP.

Comment: We need to use nodejs with lighttpd. For that we need our android device to support nodejs. From my reseach I found that i need to find the package and cross  compile the same to use further. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.